# Rich Text View like Instagram Comment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I would like to implement rich format text views as are demonstrated in Instagram. Following is a screenshot.

Specifically, my goals are:

1. Words at different positions of the same text view may have different font sizes, font colors and font styles(bold, italic, etc).
2. Touch events (long press, touch down, etc) can be detected in the delegate callbacks. Information (which word is touched, whether it's a long press or a touch down, etc) can be gathered in such callback methods.

Big frameworks like Three20 are out of the question. Small, independent libraries are highly preferred. Low level Cocoa Touch APIs may also be OK if it won't take me more than a few days to wrap them up.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found an ideal open source solution (supports both iOS 5.0 and iOS 6): the OHAttributedLabel, which is capable of both rich format and touch handling.

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Comment: In iOS6 UILabel and NSAttributedString does this too.

Comment: OHAttributedLabel supports iOS 5 ;)

Answer (score 3):

NSAttributedString lets you do this. If you have access to the iOS 5 developers cookbook by Erica Sadun there is a recipe for a wrapper around NSMutableAttributedString which makes it simple to add text piece by piece, changing attributes as you go.

[Here](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook/tree/master/C10/14-Basic%20Core%20Text) is the source on Erica's githuib

Comment: edit: this doesn't do touch handling, only the display. if you want that as well, maybe a UIWebview with different link types and a css for styling each may be better?

Comment: Thanks @wattson12 . I used the **href** thing a lot in my web views actually. I noticed that they can only detect one kind of touch event, the **touch-up-inside**. But what Instagram is capable of doing is **long press** and **touch down**.

Comment: I didnt know that about href's. I'm not too sure of this but could you use javascript to detect a long press inside the webview? like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038613/get-the-duration-of-a-touch-in-javascript)?