# JS - calc duration of mouseclick

Tags: javascript, click, duration

I wonder if there is any way to calculate mouse click in seconds.

Just to make it clear, if user keeps the mousedown for 5 seconds, I wanna write to console '5 sec' etc.

There is any way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: This [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038613/get-the-duration-of-a-touch-in-javascript) has answers with code (partially using JQuery).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure the milliseconds between mousedown and mouseup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360818/how-to-measure-the-milliseconds-between-mousedown-and-mouseup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a startDate on mouseDown then get endDate on mouseUp and calculate difference between these dates, convert second. And.... just console.log :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you should have a look at the *Date* object in Javascript, as well as to the events being fired during a click (*mousedown* is not the only one).

Comment: I really want to write a thorough answer to this question, but you really wrote a great answer here. +1.

Comment: Well thanks, there are a few tricky aspects to consider, but that's to the OP to find out and come back if he still needs help.