# How can you prevent a click from firing at the end of a long press?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, hammer.js

I ask because of this situation:

I put down my finger on a list item. After `500ms`, a Hammer `press` event is triggered, and the page shows an action sheet. After `1s`, I raise my finger, and a `click` event fires (a regular click, not one emitted by Hammer). My finger at that point is over the action sheet backdrop, which has a click handler that closes itself.

I realize using the Hammer `tap` event to close the action sheet would work, because it has a `250ms` maximum duration, but the action sheet library uses a `click` event. Is there a way to tell the browser to not fire clicks if the duration is eg `250ms`? Or to alternatively tell the browser to not emit the next click that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented the solution below based on the [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/tips/#%22after-a-tap,-also-a-click-is-being-triggered,-i-don't-want-that!%22) page discussion on disabling ghost clicks?

https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons#ghost

[hammer.js](/questions/tagged/hammer.js)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to combine https://gist.github.com/jtangelder/361052976f044200ea17 with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038613/get-the-duration-of-a-touch-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue in Ionic: ActionSheet was disappearing after touch end.

I came up with the following workaround: ignore `click` event on the element right after `pressup` event in HammerJS by using `pointer-events: none`. This solution exploits the fact that `click` event is fired on the element immediately after `pressup` event, so we are able to prevent it somehow by handling `pressup`.

In global styles I added the following helper class:

```css
.prevent-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Then, on the same element where I handle the `press` event I added a new `pressup` event handler which does the following:

```
  element.classList.add('prevent-pointer-events');

  setTimeout(() => {
    element.classList.remove('prevent-pointer-events');
  }, 50); // after 50ms we are sure the "click" event was fired and ignored,
          // so we can revert the class name back
```

Note that this solution is local, just for one element, although it can be extended to handle global `pressup` event on the document body.